# Why i am not getting the data in first call to my REST API

Tags: node.js, rest

I am making call to my REST API but on making the first call its returning an empty array and on second call only its returning the desired result.Here are my files.

mongodb.js for connecting to mongodb database

```
var MongoClient =require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var dburl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';


module.exports.connect = function connect(callback){
    MongoClient.connect(dburl, function(err, conn){
        /* exports the connection */
        if(err)
        {
            callback(err);console.log(err)
        }
        else
        {
            callback(undefined,conn.collection('person'));
            //console.log(conn)
        }

    });
};
```

getUsers.js for retrieving documents from database

```
const mongodb = require('.././mongodb/mongodb');

var v=[];
module.exports.getUser=function(callback)
{
    mongodb.connect(function(err,db)
    {
        if (err)
        {
            console.log(err)
        }
        else
        {
            data(db,function (docs) {
                //console.log(v)
                callback(v)
            })
           // console.log(v)

        }
    });
}
function data(db,callback) {
    db.find().forEach((docs)=>{
                v.push(docs)
    })
    callback(v);
}
```

server.js for starting the server

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser')
const getUsers = require('./users/getUsers');
const insertUsers = require('./users/insertUsers');
const findUsers = require('./users/findUsersEmail');
const delusers=require('./users/deleteUsers')
const moduser=require('./users/updateUser')
const app = express();
app.use(bodyparser.json())
app.get('/person', (req, res) =>
{   console.log(res.statusCode)
    if(res.statusCode==200)
    {
        getUsers.getUser(function (userList){
            res.json(userList);
            console.log(userList);

        })

    }})
app.listen(4569,()=>console.log('server has started on 4501'))
```

Comment: why are you checking `statusCode` in request itself ?

Comment: i dont think that checking the request code matters here.The point is i have to make res.send() synchronous with getUsers.getUser() so that it will execute when getUsers.getUser() has completed its task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `data` function calls the callback before the data is actually returned. The correct implementation should be:

```
const mongodb = require('.././mongodb/mongodb');

module.exports.getUser = function(callback) {
  mongodb.connect(function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      data(db, callback);
    }
  });
}

function data(db, callback) {
  db.find().toArray((err, docs) => callback(docs));
}
```

You can see that the global variable `v` is not used at all.

By the way, you should follow the NodeJS convention to implement the callback function:

```
callback(err[, ...args])
```

Skipping the error argument will give you a lot of pain when your code base grows, especially when you need to integrate with third-party libraries.